# Концептуальный вопрос касательно целого числа на Lua

Tags: lua

Здравствуйте.

Изучаю язык Lua. Пытаюсь понять коценпутальный момент: 
в языке есть только три атомических типов данных (atomic data types):
1. boolean
2. Number
3. String

Что касается Number, то копаясь в файле конфигураций https://www.lua.org/source/5.1/luaconf.h.html

существует следующее определение:

```
#define LUA_NUMBER      double
```

Не существует типа int но существует встроенные интепритатор:

```
LUA_API lua_Integer lua_tointeger (lua_State *L, int idx) {
  TValue n;
  const TValue *o = index2adr(L, idx);
  if (tonumber(o, &n)) {
    lua_Integer res;
    lua_Number num = nvalue(o);
    lua_number2integer(res, num);
    return res;
  }
  else
    return 0;
}
```

Может ли кто привести аргументы за и против такого концептуального строения языка и его атомических типов данных ?

Чем это помогает, чем осложняет в целом работу ?

Comment: в Lua 5.3 добавили integer тип как подтип number. Проблема в том что  размеры этих типов определяются на этапе компиляции. И рассчитывать на то что тип сможет вместить определенное значение можно только с определенной степенью вероятности.

Comment: мне интересен вопрос относительно старой версии 5.2. Просто как теоретически концептуальный вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Такое обоснование приводит Роберту Иерузалимски в своей книге "Программирование на языке Lua":

> Некоторые опасаются, что даже такие простые операции, как увеличение
>   на единицу (инкремент) и сравнение, могут некорректно работать с
>   числами с плавающей точкой. Однако на самом деле это не так.
>   Практически все платформы сейчас поддерживают стандарт IEEE 754 для
>   представления чисел с плавающей точкой. Согласно этому стандарту,
>   единственным возможным источником ошибок является случай, когда число
>   не может быть точно представлено. Операция округляет свой результат,
>   только если результат не может быть точно представлен в виде
>   соответствующего значения с плавающей точкой. Любая операция,
>   результат которой может быть точно представлен, будет иметь точное
>   значение.
>
> Ha самом деле любое целое число вплоть до 2^53 (приблизительно 10^16)
>   имеет точное представление в виде числа с плавающей точкой с двойной
>   точностью (double). Когда вы используете значение с плавающей точкой с
>   двойной точностью для представления целых чисел, нет никаких ошибок
>   округления, за исключением случая, когда значение по модулю
>   превосходит 2^53. ***В частности, Lua способен представлять любые
>   32-битовые целые значения без проблем с округлениями.*** Конечно, дробные
>   числа будут иметь проблемы с округлением.
>
> Прежде чем мы продолжим, запомните, целые числа имеют точное
>   представление и поэтому не имеют ошибок с округлением. ***Большинство
>   современных CPU выполняет операции с плавающей точкой так же быстро
>   (или даже быстрее), чем с целыми числами.***

Comment: Я перечитал и посмотрел в самой книге. Мне из этого не до конца понятно, почему был лишен тип int и какие могут быть от этого плюсы и минусы. Кроме как, что вычисления типа double не уступают по скорости вычеслением с целыми числами.

Comment: Это было просто удобно. Язык использовался как конфигурационный. Так же не было необходимости поддерживать Int64. В Lua  5.3 как раз и добавили эту поддержку.

Comment: @Ilya.K. Когда создавался язык Lua (середина девяностых), в Си ещё небыло поддержки Int64 (тип `long long` появился только в С99), а поскольку `double` прекрасно справляется с int32, то и небыло смысла в отдельном типе. Хотя, стоит заметить, что вначале вообще использовался тип `float`, а на `double` перешли именно для того, чтобы вмещались инты. Доклад Иерузалимски на эту тему: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bjqNK1jA77M